# When exactly is the head of a Stream evaluated?

Tags: scala, stream, lazy-evaluation

Normally if you create a `Stream` object, the head will be eagerly evaluated:

```
scala> Stream( {println("evaluating 1"); 1} , 2, 3)
evaluating 1
res63: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)
```

If we create a Stream to which we prepend in the same statement, it seems slightly surprising that the head is not evaluated prior to the concatenation. i.e.

```
scala> 0 #:: Stream( {println("evaluating 1"); 1} , 2, 3)
res65: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(0, ?)
```

(`#::` is right-associative and is the prepend method on `ConsWrapper`, which is an implicit class of `Stream`.)

How does this not evaluate its head before prepending the 0? Is it that the tail Stream (or cons cell) does not exist on the heap until we take values from the resultant Stream? But if so, how do we call the `#::` method on an object that doesn't exist yet?

Comment: I suggest you use `javap` to understand what is going on.

Comment: I figured it out looking at the source (assuming my answer is correct)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`-Xprint:typer` is your friend, any time you want to understand exactly how some code is evaluated or types are inferred.

```
scala -Xprint:typer -e '0 #:: Stream( {println("evaluating 1"); 1} , 2, 3)'

val x$1: Int = 0;
Stream.consWrapper[Int](Stream.apply[Int]({
  println("evaluating 1");
  1
}, 2, 3)).#::(x$1)
```

The parameter of [`consWrapper`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.1/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.scala#L588) is by-name. So even this works:

```
scala> (1 #:: (sys.error("!!"): Stream[Int])).head
res1: Int = 1
```

Comment: +1 for using `-e`. I think it's so little used compared to, say, Perl's.

Comment: I get it now. Also important is that the implicit def from Stream to ConsWrapper is by-name. `implicit def consWrapper[A](stream: => Stream[A])`. This is presumably why `ConsWrapper` exists, and `#::` isn't a method on `Stream` directly: so that the Stream doesn't have to be created to call this method - you just get a `ConsWrapper` object that contains the subset of functionality.

Answer (score 5):

The head is evaluated in the moment the Stream is created.

But in you second example you don't pass a Streem as the second argument to `#::` you pass a  by name parameter, i.e. the complete expression `Stream( {println("evaluating 1"); 1} , 2, 3)` isn't evaluated at all.