# Scala Streams: Self-Reference, Function Calls and Lazy Evaluation

Tags: scala, stream, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to understand why the following code using Scala Streams doesn't work:

```scala
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  lazy val y : SimNumericStream = y.shift
  y.scalstream.take(10).print
}

class SimNumericStream( ss : Stream[Double] )  {  
  lazy val scalstream = ss
  lazy val shift = new SimNumericStream( 0 #:: scalstream )
}
```

and yet replacing

```scala
lazy val y : SimNumericStream = y.shift
```

by

```scala
lazy val y : SimNumericStream = new SimNumericStream( 0 #:: y.scalstream )
```

works just fine.

I'm looking for a solution that allows to me wrap up operations on Streams inside functions without breaking the lazy evaluation when the streams are self-referential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved the effect I would like through the following:

```
  class SimNumericStream(str: =>Stream[Double]) {
    def ::(hd: Double) = Stream.cons(hd, str)
    def shift = 0.0 :: this
  }
  implicit def streamToSimNumericStream(str: =>Stream[Double]) = new SimNumericStream(str)

  lazy val y: Stream[Double] = y.shift
```

Answer (score 4):

In your first version, your call to instantiate `SimNumericStream` is inside an instance of `SimNumericStream`, so you can never actually intantiate one unless you have one already.

Comment: Thanks, but:

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      lazy val shift = ( sns : SimNumericStream ) => new SimNumericStream( 0 #:: sns.scalstream )
      lazy val y : SimNumericStream = shift(y)
      y.scalstream.take(10).print
    }

Also produces the same (runtime) error whereas (manual) inlining of the function does not.

Comment: @George in that snippet you have just moved the problem into a function: you can still only make a new instance if you have an instance already. It's fine to be self-referential, but a self-replicating object has to have something else to create the first one.

Comment: I guess I am struggling to see why this issue is also not present in the version that works. In that case we also have the "new SimNumericStream" within the definition of the same SimNumericStream (y). Self-replication is not what I'm looking for, just self reference.
Perhaps asking the question another way, how would you define a "shift" function that returns a shifted stream and then use that function within the definition of the stream that's being shifted? Is there another way?

Comment: @George I guess I don't understand what you think is wrong with the solution that you say works fine; it doesn't break lazy evaluation as far as I can see. I just thought I'd provide an explanation of why the version that fails does so, since it fails a basic sanity-check.

Comment: what is wrong with it as far as I am concerned is the need for the calling code to look inside the SimNumericStream object: I should be able to implement the shift operator on the SimNumericStream object itself, hiding the implementation using Scala streams under the hood. Am I wrong, or does the fact that one form works whereas the other doesn't break the idea of referential transparency?

Comment: @George of course you can have a "shift" method on your object to produce a new one, but your snippet that doesn't work is like `lazy val x: String = x.toUpperCase`. What's x? Referential transparency isn't broken because the two lines of code are different: one is `0 #:: scalstream` while the other is `0 #:: y.scalstream`.

Comment: it's not like `lazy val x: String = x.toUpperCase` because in your snippet every character in that string needs to have a value before one can compute its upper case. Not so with my example. My example is more like `lazy val x: String = "A" + x`. This is (conceptually) an infinite string of A's. However, lazy evaluation is not supported via Strings in Scala (AFAIK) and so actually executing that snippet gives me a stack overflow. However, re-writing in terms of streams gives me the equivalent `lazy val x: Stream[Char] = 'A' #:: x`. This works perfectly, e.g. println(x(1)) prints 'A'.

Comment: @George In that example `x` is an argument, rather than the object on which you're calling a method. Furthermore `#::` triggers an implicit conversion to `ConsWrapper`, which takes a by-name argument, meaning it's evaluated lazily. This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857103/when-exactly-is-the-head-of-a-stream-evaluated